# SQL Group by One Field First Than Another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that lists information about a customers reservation. I need to group customers that are staying in the same rooms together (Identified by having the same `sharer_code`). However, I also need to be able to search other tables based on their `reservation_number` (Unique to each persons reservation).

I have the following query that pulls each reservation and lists their arrival date, departure date, room they are staying in, number of people on that reservation, and the amounts they are spending. Here is the query:

```
SELECT c.reservation_number, c.arrival_date, c.departure_date, r.room_type_code, p.number_of_persons, SUM(r.room_revenue + r.package_revenue) AS amount, SUM(r.spa_revenue) AS spa_revenue
FROM nw_src.dbo.customer_res c
JOIN nw_src.dbo.customer_resx p ON c.reservation_number = p.reservation_number
JOIN nw_src.dbo.res_revenue r ON c.reservation_number = r.reservation_number
WHERE c.cancellation_number = 0
GROUP BY c.reservation_number, c.arrival_date, c.departure_date, r.room_type_code, p.number_of_persons
ORDER BY c.reservation_number
```

This lists each reservation one-by-one. I need to group them by if the `sharer_code` in `customer_res` is the same. Here is a sample of the `customer_res` table:

`reservation_number | arrival_date | departure_date | sharer_code
      10002            2017-04-21      2017-04-23        10004
      10003            2017-04-11      2017-04-12            0
      10004            2017-04-21      2017-04-23        10004
      10008            2017-04-21      2017-04-23        10004
      10009            2017-05-06      2017-05-08            0
      10010            2017-04-28      2017-04-30        10010`

In the above, reservation `10002` and `10008` are in a group but on separate reservations (or on different bills) identified by the `sharer_code`. Their group reservation was assigned the number `10004.

Reservation `10003` and `10009` are people that could be in a group or not, but either way are all on one bill so there will not be other reservation numbers to group them with.

Here is a sample of the `customer_resx` table:

`reservation_number | number_of_persons
        10002                 1
        10003                 4
        10008                 1
        10009                 2`

This helps clarify the above. `10002` and `10008` are staying in the same room but are on separate bills so they have only "1" person on each reservation. However `10003` and `10009` have multiple people staying in a room as well but they are all on one bill (or "reservation").

Here is a sample of the `res_revenue` table:

`reservation_number | room_type_code | room_revenue | package_revenue | spa_revenue
      10002              1cat             -150             560             195
      10002              1cat             -150             560             315
      10002              1cat                0               0             190
      10003              1dol              236            1120             400
      10003              1dol                0               0             245
      10008              1cat             -150             560             125
      10008              1cat             -150             560             290
      10008              1cat                0               0             120
      10009              1cyn            332.8           591.2              20
      10009              1cyn            332.8           591.2             390
      10009              1cyn                0               0             230`

And this is where it's super clear. `10002` and `10008` are both staying in `1cat` meaning they are a group and we need to group them all together. `10003` is in their own room, `1dol`. And `10009` is in `1cyn`.

And finally, here is what I would LIKE the result set to look like:

`reservation_number | arrival_date | departure_date | room_type_code | number_of_persons | amount | spa_revenue
      10002            2017-04-21      2017-04-23        1cat        2     1640     1235
      10003            2017-04-11      2017-04-12        1dol        4     1356      645
      10009            2017-05-06      2017-05-08        1cyn        2     1848      640`

Please note that the `reservation_number` can be either `10002`, `10004`, or `10008`. This would be something like `MIN`, `sharer_code`, or `MAX`.

Comment: TLDR it's entirely, because it was hard to follow, but looks like you want to do your initial aggregations in a  `CTE` and then aggregate that result set again (with different groupings of course)

Comment: Do you have the option to redesign the database? I feel like you'd have an easier time if you could normalize some of these tables. For example, why is reservation_number repeating in res_revenue?

Comment: @mallan1121 unfortunately I do not have that option or I would have, trust me.